# Is GPG request routed through Tor or should I use torify? (Tails)

Tags: tails, torify

Is a default GPG request routed through Tor by default on Tails or should I wrap it around Torify.

For example: `gpg --receive-keys "0x2bd5824b7f9470e6"`

or it should be: `torify gpg --receive-keys "0x2bd5824b7f9470e6"`

I have seen that Tails routes most traffic through tor but I am not sure if the terminal commands are too, so should I use torify here or not?

(I am also askin about [seahorse's](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Seahorse/) **"Find Remote Keys"** option, is that routed through Tor or not?)

Answer (score 0):

Everything on Tails either goes through Tor or cannot connect to the internet.

In Tails, GnuPG's `dirmngr` (which is used to fetch keys), is configured to use Tor by default.

The request will go over Tor even without `torify`.

Comment: so what is the point of torify then?

Comment: Other applications may not be configured to go over Tor by default. gpg is, however.

Answer (score 0):

Tails is supposed to be to route all **from the guest VM's** through Tor, so it depends on where are you calling it from. Use QubesOS and be free from these OOB problems. If you need more help - just drop me a line!